# How to make sure if custom sdk can be used for only one play store app?

Tags: android

I am new to android ECO System. I am just writing a code and created .aar file which other developer can use this.

1) Is it possible to make sure only one application can be developed and uploaded to app store using this aar file.if I provide to another developer.

2) Other than this developer, it should not be used by others. For this probably i can go with API Key Concept. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface_key)

Comment: 1: App must be signed by your key, and App must have it's own unique package name. Did you mean this?   http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. No not that way.  Let's example, if i purchase xamarin SDK, i can develop only one application and upload into play store. This SDK can not be used by other developer not targeted for. How this mechanism to be driven?  https://store.xamarin.com/